# Dispay sidebar contents based on selected tabpanel

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a shiny dashboard with two sliders in the sidebar and two tab panels in the body. What I want to achieve is to display only "slider1" when I select "slider1" tab panel and only "slider2" when I select "slider2" tab panel.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    uiOutput("slider1"),
    uiOutput("slider2")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = 'testingDPEtab',
      tabPanel("slider1"
      ),
      tabPanel("slider2"
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$slider1<-renderUI({
    sliderInput("slider1", label = h3("Slider1"), min = 0, 
                max = 100, value = 50)
  })
  output$slider2<-renderUI({
    sliderInput("slider2", label = h3("Slider2"), min = 0, 
                max = 200, value = 50)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

Here's a working solution using shinyJS:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    useShinyjs(),
    uiOutput("slider1"),
    uiOutput("slider2")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = 'testingDPEtab',
      tabPanel("slider1Tab"),
      tabPanel("slider2Tab")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  shinyjs::hide(id="slider1")
  shinyjs::hide(id="slider2")
  output$slider1<-renderUI({
    sliderInput("slider1", label = h3("Slider1"), min = 0,
                max = 100, value = 50)
  })
  output$slider2<-renderUI({
    sliderInput("slider2", label = h3("Slider2"), min = 0,
                max = 200, value = 50)
  })

  observe({
    if(input$testingDPEtab == "slider1Tab"){
      shinyjs::show(id="slider1")
      shinyjs::hide(id="slider2")
    } else {
      shinyjs::hide(id="slider1")
      shinyjs::show(id="slider2")
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This might be better if you want to preserve your slider (i.e. hide it) instead of re-rendering it.

---

ORIGINAL POST

I was going to suggest using [shinyJs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyjs/shinyjs.pdf) but I couldn't get it to work - maybe because the sliders are being set up in the server side instead of in the UI?

So I took an alternative approach and wrapped your 2 renderUI function calls in an observe() event. I use an if/else statement to set one control on and the second control off based on the selected tab. Seems to work ok.

```
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    uiOutput("slider1"),
    uiOutput("slider2")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(
      id = 'testingDPEtab',
      tabPanel("slider1Tab"),
      tabPanel("slider2Tab")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    if(input$testingDPEtab == "slider1Tab"){
      output$slider1<-renderUI({
        sliderInput("slider1", label = h3("Slider1"), min = 0, 
                    max = 100, value = 50)
      })
      output$slider2<-NULL
    } else {
      output$slider1<-NULL
      output$slider2<-renderUI({
        sliderInput("slider2", label = h3("Slider2"), min = 0, 
                    max = 200, value = 50)
      })
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

If not necessary I usually try to avoid rendering UI elements.

Here is a solution using conditionalPanels.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyApp(

ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),

    dashboardSidebar(
        conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.tabselected == 1",
            sliderInput("slider1", label = h3("Slider1"), min = 0, 
                    max = 100, value = 50)),
        conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.tabselected == 2",
        sliderInput("slider2", label = h3("Slider2"), min = 0, 
                    max = 200, value = 50))
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        tabsetPanel(
            id = "tabselected",
            tabPanel("slider1", value = 1
            ),
            tabPanel("slider2", value = 2
            )
        )
    )
),

server = function(input, output) {

}
)
```